# Controller for greenhouse control system

Tags: arduino, pic, control, sbc

I'm working in a project where we are developing a greenhouse control system, to take care of temperature, humidity...

For the first step where we only log the parameters to an SD we have been using an Arduino board, but now we want to improve the system and add fans, humidifier, light sensing and control algorithms to maintain the greenhouse at a constant state.

Because of the grow of the system we can't use the Arduino anymore, we are looking for a SBC or Microcontroller board, powerful enough to do the job but we don't want a painful migration, we are looking for a easy to use board with RTOS or ever better embedded Linux. And if it is possible it shouldn't be so expensive.

Do you know some product that fits our needs? or Could you recommend me another solution?

Thanks you all :)

Comment: How many devices do you plan on controlling or monitoring?

Comment: Hi, mainly 3 or 4 fans and one humidifier in the hi-voltage side, and some sensors and small actuators in the logic side.

Comment: Is there a reason the Arduino you have doesn't allow the new functionality you want?

Answer (score 4):

Just take a nettop PC then ;-)
<200$ and lots of time saved on development & debugging.

Comment: A nettop may not be suitable in a greenhouse environment, but it is a simple solution.

Comment: Modern ones consume just about 10W when little load. You can go down to 1W by going for slower uC, but it will triple time expenses, I am not really sure it's worth it.

Comment: @jsolarski Why would a nettop be any less suitable for a greenhouse environment than any other offered options?

Comment: @AndrejaKo From my experience, fan-less PCs (nettops/thin clients) only last for a few years in that kind of environment.

Comment: @jsolarski I still see no reason why that should be so, but I'll take your experience into account if I ever come into similar situation as OP.

Comment: @AndrejaKo It may be the case design and placement that caused those failures, but it is something to consider if its supposed to be a permanent installation. I would not want to choose a nettop that doesn't have a suitable case for the environment.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to have the right answer for this question. Despite I have some suggestions.

- You can use [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org/)

[image: Beagleboard]

- [FriendlyArm](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/mini2440)

[image: FriendlyArm overview]
[image: FriendlyArm running Android]

- Or even the [mbed](http://mbed.org/)

[image: mbed]

Comment: Hi, I didn't know about FriendlyARM, it looks quite nice and i like the screen :)

Comment: @SubniC, the photo was taken by a friend of mine here in Brazil. http://www.sergioprado.org/2010/09/12/mini2440-instalando-o-android/